# How do you give supervisor powers to SimpleMDM?

Tags: mobile-device-management

I have an iPhone iOS 9 it has been place under supervision via Apple Configurator. I cannot seem to transfer supervisor powers to SimpleMDM.

How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Supervision is a mode that a device is put into. If you successfully put the device in Supervised mode, SimpleMDM will be able to take advantage of the added control. You can enroll the device as you normally would.